# $\omega_1=\omega_2$ if $\cos(\omega_1t-\phi_1)=\cos(\omega_2t-\phi_2)$ for every $t \in [0,+\infty)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I'm in trouble (again) with the following simple trigonometric equation:

$\cos(\omega_1t-\phi_1)=\cos(\omega_2t-\phi_2)$

which holds for every $t \in [0,+\infty)$, with $\phi_1,\phi_2 \in [0,2\pi]$ fixed and $\omega_1,\omega_2>0$ fixed. **I need to show that $\omega_1=\omega_2$**, but I can't see how.

$ $

My attemp:

Taking $t=0$ we have that $\cos(\phi_1)=\cos(\phi_2)$ which means that $\phi_1=\phi_2$ or $\phi_1=2\pi-\phi_2$. Let's take for example $\phi_1=\phi_2$. Then we have that:

$\forall \,t \in [0,+\infty) \quad \cos(\omega_1t-\phi_1)=\cos(\omega_2t-\phi_1)$

and then:

$\forall \,t \in [0,+\infty) \quad \exists \,n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \omega_1t-\phi_1=\omega_2t-\phi_1+2n\pi \quad$ or $\quad \omega_1t-\phi_1=-(\omega_2t-\phi_1)+2n\pi$

With simple calculation we get to:

$(\omega_1-\omega_2)t=2n\pi \quad$ or $\quad (\omega_1+\omega_2)t-2\phi_1=2n\pi$

Now if we suppose (by *reductio ad absurdum*) that $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$ we can take $t=\frac{2}{\omega_1-\omega_2}$ and so we have:

$n\pi=1 \quad$ or $\quad \frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{\omega_1-\omega_2}-\phi_1=n\pi$

The first equation is obviously false for every integer, but the second one could be true. If we could prove that even the second one is false, then we should have that $\omega_1=\omega_2$. **Am I right? Is there an easier way?** Thank you!

Comment: Assume $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$? I believe it should lead to an immidiate contradiction.

Comment: Actually, I can't see how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating twice with respect to $t$ yields
$$\omega_1^2 (-\cos(\omega_1 t - \phi_1)) = \omega_2^2 (-\cos(\omega_2 t - \phi_2)).$$
Since $-\cos(\omega_1 t - \phi_1) = -\cos(\omega_2 t - \phi_2)$, this says that $\omega_1^2 = \omega_2^2$, hence $|\omega_1| = |\omega_2|$.